# Conditional grouping in R

Tags: r

I am looking for guidance to solve for a scenario in R where I have a list of customer_ID and date_mailed. customer_ID is the unique ID for each customer and the date_mailed contains dates for when a mail was sent to these customers. I'm looking to get a group count of number of mails sent by customer_ID where each group would be mails that were sent less than 90 days apart. Example dataset:

[image: Example Dataset]
Difference between 2/28 and 6/1 for customer_ID 123 is 93 days so that would make it 2 groups. Here's the desired output:
Just to be clear, even though Customer_ID 123 is same, but the gap between 4th row 123 and 3rd row 123 is more than 90 days, I am expected to group first three 123 together and next two 123 together.

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: So if a customer is sent three emails, 80 days between each, is that one group (because there is not more than 90 days in between) or something else? Please don't include images of code or data: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)

Comment: @r2evans -  If we send three emails to customer, 80 days between each that should be considered as one group. A fresh mail is only when no mail is sent to customer in last 90 days. Regarding images, this is my first post and the site was not allowing me to post the table. And this was my first post, so wasn't aware how to post to keep table format intact

Comment: How is it coming with providing sample data? (Referenced in Ronak's comment.) Preferring something like `dput(head(x))`.

Comment: 1 123 1/1/2019
2 123 1/15/2019
3 123 2/28/2019
4 123 6/1/2019
5 123 6/15/2019
6 456 1/12/2019
7 456 2/11/2019
8 456 3/11/2019
9 890 2/1/2019
10 890 5/31/2019
11 890 6/6/2019
12 576 6/1/2017
13 576 7/12017
14 576 1/1/2018
15 576 2/1/2018
16 576 2/2/2018
17 576 1/5/2019

Comment: 1 123 3
2 123 2
3 456 3
4 576 1
5 576 5
6 890 1
7 890 2

Comment: I am getting above output. Getting only two rows for each Customer_ID, when I should be getting more than 2 for few

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date_Mailed = as.Date(Date_Mailed, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  count(
    Customer_ID, 
    grp = cumsum(c(0, +(Date_Mailed > (lag(Date_Mailed) + 90))[-1])),
    name = 'Group_Mail_Count'
  ) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Output:

```
  Customer_ID Group_Mail_Count
        <dbl>            <int>
1         123                3
2         123                2
3         456                3
4         890                1
5         890                2
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Date_Mailed := as.Date(Date_Mailed, "%m/%d/%Y")][
  , .(Group_Mail_Count = .N), by = .(Customer_ID, 
                                    cumsum(c(0, +(Date_Mailed > (lag(Date_Mailed) + 90))[-1])))
][, 'cumsum' := NULL]
```

Output:

```
   Customer_ID Group_Mail_Count
1:         123                3
2:         123                2
3:         456                3
4:         890                1
5:         890                2
```

Comment: Above solution doesn't work. For above data, even though Customer_ID 123 and 890 should have two rows, I am getting only one row each for 123 and 890. Please could you help ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(nameofyourdataframe, 10))`? It should work, likely the problem is the type of your columns or something similar. But you need to provide `dput`, otherwise debugging can be tricky.

Comment: 1 123 1/1/2019 2 123 1/15/2019 3 123 2/28/2019 4 123 6/1/2019 5 123 6/15/2019 6 456 1/12/2019 7 456 2/11/2019 8 456 3/11/2019 9 890 2/1/2019 10 890 5/31/2019 11 890 6/6/2019 12 576 6/1/2017 13 576 7/12017 14 576 1/1/2018 15 576 2/1/2018 16 576 2/2/2018 17 576 1/5/2019  - Data used

Comment: 1 123 3 2 123 2 3 456 3 4 576 1 5 576 5 6 890 1 7 890 2

Comment: For Customer_ID 576 there should have been three rows, 576 2, 576 3, 576 1

Comment: This is not the output of `dput`. We need to know things like type of columns and perhaps also other information about your data frame.